# Metamask confirm button is blue, but doesn't respond to clicks(taps) in the mobile app

Tags: metamask

We're developing a dapp and using Metamask for user to deposit token from their web3 wallet to the mobile app balance. Everything works well until last week. When our users try to deposit token. The blue confirm button appears but doesn't respond to taps.

This issue happens for both testnet and mainnet. We tried with 5 iPhones and android phones, same issue.

[image]

Comment: You should contact Metamask customer support, it seems to be an issue on their side.

Comment: @klinh718 Can you please let me know, how is it fixed, even I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @PuneetTiwari actually it hasn't been fixed :( It works for me in some transactions then doesn't work again